# How can I make assertions from script code of a BSF Post Processor?

Tags: java, javascript, jmeter, functional-testing, stress-testing

I'm trying to build a test suite using a JMetter.
The web-service I'm tring to test speaks some custom-made protocol, and expressing my needs using regular expressions makes it very difficult.

Then I found the BSF Post processor, that allows me to execute some Java Script codes - and that's great.

But - what would be really awsome - is if I could make the assertions I want to do from the script body I provide the BSF post processor.

Can anybody point me to the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try the [BSF Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Assertion) control - allows assertions to be made using BSF script code. It's much like the post processor really but it also sets up the AssertionResult variable which has the setFailure method.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the new [JSR 223](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) family as it will get better performances starting from JMeter 2.8 or current nightly build.